# Multi selection of rows in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to implement multi selection of rows via keyboard (Shift+Up arrow/Shift+Down arrow). Honestly, I've no idea to implement this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

What You can do in Kendo Grid is providing a multi-selection mecanisme using ctrl button. So the user presses ctrl and then clicks on the rows that he wants to select (ctrl + left mouse click).
If this is what you look for, here is a code sample:

```
 $("#rowSelection").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            data: orders,
                        },
                        selectable: "multiple",
                        .
                        .
                        .  
                    });
```

The key syntax is: **selectable: "multiple"**.

Comment: I think it doesn't work with "Shift+Up arrow/Shift+Down arrow".
It will works only with "Shift/ctrl + Left Mouse click".
Please enlighten me if I am worng! Any way +1 from me.

Comment: I've mentioned in the answer that it does not work with "Shift+Up arrow/Shift+Down arrow" and that it works with "ctrl + left mouse click". Yet, that's a good that you said that it also works with "Shift + left mouse click". +1

Comment: Thanks for the answer @HamdiBaligh.. But I'm trying to minimize the use of the mouse. That's a requirement.